# Jqgrid is showing blank fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a piece of code the purpose of the code is to use entityframework and generate jqgrid.I am successful in doing this task but jqgrid is showing blank fields. Please help. Please see the attached images.

Jqgrid is showing blank:

[image]

```
$(function () {
$("#ListGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "/TodoList/GetTodoLists",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: ['FirstName', 'Gender', 'Id', 'Lastname', 'Salary'],
    colModel: [            
        { key: false, name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', editable: true },
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'Lastname', index: 'Lastname', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', editable: true }],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Todo List',
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false
}).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true },
    {
        // edit options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: '/TodoList/Edit',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {

            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        // add options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/TodoList/Create",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        // delete options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/TodoList/Delete",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: can you share code that you use to populate the grid

Comment: Thanks for your reply Totalo.Is this the one required?

Comment: Add `loadonce:true,`.

Comment: Thank for your reply.it didn't work Jai